# Nullptr error during adding structures to list

Tags: c

I've written my own list in C, but during adding 2nd object to it I've `Exception thrown: write access violation. It occures in addToList() function (I've commented the line). Can you tell me why i'm getting an error. I've initialized head in main method:

```
void main()
{
    struct List *head = malloc(sizeof(head));
    head->next = NULL;
    head->person = NULL;
    //head = NULL;
    addToList(head,"Abdul","Marin","21312321321");
    addToList(head, "Karmowski", "Byk", "24214541");
    displayList(head);
    getchar();
    return 0;

}
```

**List.h file:**

```
 struct List
    {
        struct Person *person;
        struct List *next;
    };
```

**List.c file:**

```
void addToList(struct List * head, char *name, char *surname, char *id)
{
    struct List *tmp = head;
    struct Osoba *newPerson= malloc(sizeof *newPerson);
    newPerson->name = name;
    newPerson->surname = surname;
    newPerson->id = id;
    if (tmp->person==NULL)
    {
        head->person = newPerson;
    }
    else if (tmp->next==NULL)
    {
        head->next->person = newPerson; // HERE OCCURES ERROR
    }
    else
    {
        while (tmp->next!=NULL)
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next->person = newPerson;
    }

}
```

Comment: You established that `tmp = head` and that `tmp->next == NULL`, so why do you expect to be able to access `head->next->person`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**/*function definition for add data in list */
struct list * AddList ( struct list *head, char *name, char *surname, int id )
{
        struct person *new_person = NULL ;
        struct list *newlist = NULL ;
        struct list *tmp = head ;

        /* memory allocation for new person */
        new_person = ( struct person * ) malloc ( sizeof ( struct person )) ;
        if ( NULL == new_person ) {
                perror ( "new node malloc failed : \n" ) ;
                return NULL ;
        }

        /* Assign value */
        strcpy( new_person->name , name ) ;
        strcpy( new_person->surname , surname ) ;
        new_person->id = id ;

        /* Assign data for head node */
        if ( NULL == head->person  ) {
                head->person = new_person ;
                return head ;
        } else if ( NULL == head->next ) { /* 2nd Node */
                newlist = ( struct list * ) malloc ( sizeof( struct list ) );
                newlist->person = new_person;
                newlist->next = NULL ;
                head->next = newlist ;
                return head->next ;
        } else { /* New list */
                while ( tmp->next ) {
                        tmp = tmp->next ;
                }

                /* memory allocation for new list */
                newlist = ( struct list * ) malloc ( sizeof( struct list ) );
                newlist->person = new_person;
                newlist->next = NULL ;
                tmp->next = newlist ;
                return head->next ;
        }
        return NULL ;
}
```

## Comments :

- You have not yet allocated  memory for new list.
- Assigned value should be wrong in elseif and else block.
- Here i have attached the basic version of my code.I will add version2 shortly

Answer (score 0):

Here is one problem

```
struct List *tmp = head;
struct Osoba *newPerson= malloc(sizeof *newPerson);
newPerson->name = name;
newPerson->surname = surname;
newPerson->id = id;
if (tmp->person==NULL)
```

You cannot assign name to newPerson->name and expect it to persist beyond the scope of the function.

You need to allocate space for name and surname and then copy the string there

e.g.

```
 newPerson->name = strdup(name);  // malloc/strcpy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (tmp->next==NULL)
{
    head->next = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    head->next->person = newPerson; 
    head->next->next = NULL;
}
```

and the same in the last else block.

Though in fact the middle block is unnecessary; if `tmp->next==NULL` then the while loop will be jumped the first time, so you don't need to treat it as a separate case.

Also your initial malloc looks wrong:

```
struct List *head = malloc(sizeof(head));
```

head is a pointer. You've been using sizeof(*head), but I don't like that; better `(sizeof(struct Person))` (it is the *type* that dictates the sizeof, not the instance).

Comment: `sizeof struct Person` ==> `sizeof(struct Person)`. The parantheses are necessary if it is a type and optional if it is a variable.

Comment: using sizeof(*head) does mean that if the type of head ever changes, you don't need to worry about updating the call to `malloc` though

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to allocate memory to `head -> next` before accessing it.

**Add**

`head->next = malloc(sizeof struct List);`

**Just before**

`head->next->person = newPerson; // HERE OCCURES ERROR`